# Serial port receives weird data from time to time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, serial-port

I using an Arduino micro-controller with the simplest piece of code possible :

```
void loop(){Serial.write('b');}
```

So it sends a constant stream of 'b'.
On the other hand, I'm using Visual Studio to receive the data :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

LPCTSTR comPort = TEXT("COM3");

int main()
{

    HANDLE hSerial;
    hSerial = CreateFile(comPort,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            //serial port does not exist. Inform user.
            cout << "ERROR WITH COM PORT" << endl;
        }
        //some other error occurred. Inform user.
    }

    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) {
        //error getting state
        cout << "ERROR GETTING SERIAL STATE" << endl;
    }
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) {
        //error setting serial port state
        cout << "ERROR SETTING SERIAL STATE" << endl;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 5;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 5;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 5;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts)) {
        //error occureed. Inform user
        cout << "ERROR SETTING TIMEOUT" << endl;
    }

    const int n = 500;
    char szBuff[n + 1] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    if (!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL)) {
        //error occurred. Report to user.
        cout << "ERROR READING FROM ARDUINO" << endl;
    }
    cout << szBuff << endl;
    //cout << szBuff << endl;

    CloseHandle(hSerial);
}
```

When I build and run, the console shows me this :
[image]

Or sometimes this :
[image]

Any ideas why ? I followed all the instructions of this guide : http://bd.eduweb.hhs.nl/micprg/pdf/serial-win.pdf and I tried a lot of things (changing the TimeOut, the numbers of bytes to receive, ...)

Sincerely yours

EDIT : I forgot to tell you that the Arduino is completely fine. I use Matlab to receive way more data and it works perfectly (no weird behavior like right now).

Comment: You are printing direct szBuff, ideally you should print only dwBytesRead size data present inside szBuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : I have to add those 3 lines :

```
dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
PurgeComm(hSerial, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
```

I think the first line prevents those weird character to pass trough the serial port and the second line flushes the buffer in case those weird characters passed before the first line.

Answer (score 0):

As you seemed to have concluded yourself, apparently from trial and error adding random things here and there, simple does not always lead to the right answer.

The code on your Arduino runs wild ahead of itself and keeps overwriting its TX buffer, hence corrupting the data. To fix it you just need to `Serial.flush()` after writing and maybe add a short delay (or just go with the delay as you've done).

The other two lines you took out of your magician hat have nothing to do with your funny chars.

As a funny side note, this is the first time after reading a Q&A here that I have the suspicion it's been written by a quasi-AI bot (I hope you take it as a compliment).